# I am trying to delete an object in my game when it of the screen but "del ObjecName" doesn't work

Tags: python, class, pygame

I am fairly new to classes so I apologise if my problem is something very basic. I want to delete the Enemy when it goes off the screen. I searched this online and found a similar Stackoverflow page which I understood I need to do something like `del Enemy` however It doesn't seem to work. I have

```
def __del__(self):
    print("object deleted")
```

method in my Enemy class so it should output that it has been deleted.

Here is my function in which I try to delete the object:

```
def enemy_actions(enemies, enemy_clock):


    if enemy_clock == 1:

        free_lanes = 0
        free_lane_positions = []
        new_enemies_lanes = []
        print("creating enemies")




        #going through all lanes
        for i in lanes:
            lane_taken = i[1]   


            if not lane_taken:

                #counting how many free lanes there are
                free_lanes = free_lanes + 1

                #adding free lane position to a list
                free_lane_positions.append(i[0])




        #if atleast 2 lanes are free then we randomly select how many new enemies we will add
        if free_lanes > 1:



            #randomly selecting how many enemies will be added
            number_of_enemies = random.randint(1,len(free_lane_positions) - 1)


            #repeating action for the number of enemies required
            for i in range(number_of_enemies):

                #randomly selecting lanes for enemies
                lane_x = random.choice(free_lane_positions)


                #adding it to the list of taken lanes
                new_enemies_lanes.append(lane_x)



                #removing taken up lane from list of free lanes
                free_lane_positions.remove(lane_x)

                #marking lane_x as taken in lanes
                for i in lanes:
                    if i[0] == lane_x:
                        i.remove(False)
                        i.append(True)

            #(self, place, x, y, length, width, path, speed):
            #building enemy 
            for i in new_enemies_lanes:
                Enemy = enemy(screen, i, enemy_y_start, 60, 60, enemy_path, random.randint(8,13))
                enemies.append(Enemy)



    #chekcing if the nemy if of the screen
    for Enemy in enemies:
        if Enemy.y > 650:
            del Enemy
```

```
enemies
```

is a list tostore all enemies. 
Please tell me if more code is required. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rebuild the enemies list without the ones you don’t want:

```
#checking if the enemy is off the screen
enemies = [enemy for enemy in enemies if enemy.y <= 650]
```